# Upgrades from previous versions

Tags: installation, repository, release-management, release-upgrade

I have couple of questions about upgrades:

1. Why is Ubuntu still including the release name in the `sources.list`? The package manager could get this information from `/etc/lsb-release`. And it's really not necessary to change this file every time one upgrades.
2. Is there a way to list packages installed by the user? It would be useful to be able to quickly install everything one had installed in previous releases, without installing system level packages that are no longer used by the distribution (such as hal).

Comment: sorry - I dont understand what you have written.  If english is not your native language, perhaps you can use google-translate to help here?

Answer (score 0):

How I can get list all packages installed by myself system(except their dependency) .
Then package manager can learn system version from /etc/lsb-release? Because now you have to put distro name in source file for each source. It's really stupid. And for keep sources necessary change system name for each line in file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Updating `sources.list` really isn't much of a problem. `update-manager` handles it all for you. It is useful to have sources that don't have the same code-name as the release (including things like security updates, which are `$release-security`.
2. I believe software center lets you see what packages you had installed previously.